# setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil crash in iphone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsobject

i am new to iphone app development and i am getting this exception at below code line,can anyone please help me to solve this?

**error**

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: varText)'
```

**code**

```
 [bodyDict setObject:textobj.varText forKey:TEXT_KEY];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initially you get the nil value from `textobj.varText`, So  check the string length is empty or not

```
if([textobj.varText length] != 0)
  [bodyDict setObject:textobj.varText forKey:TEXT_KEY];
else
  [bodyDict setObject:@"" forKey:TEXT_KEY];
```

Comment: can u help me for one more issue?

Answer (score 3):

Short and most readable method:

```
bodyDict [TEXT_KEY] = textobj.varText ?: @"";
```

?: operator checks whether the first operand is nil. It returns the first operand if it isn't nil, and the second operand if the first operand is nil.